# Missing "]" after element list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

Here's the code:

```
db.employee.aggregate([
    {$facet: 
        {"total": [$count: "total"]}
    }, 
    {$project:
        {"total": 1}
    }
])
```

```
2020-03-26T09:55:35.634+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list :
@(shell):1:49
```

As far as I can see, I'm not missing any brackets. The code is just me testing some stuff btw while I'm learning, that's why it looks like I've gone the long way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like some curly brackets are missing:

`{"total": [$count: "total"]}` -> `{"total": [{$count: "total"}]}`

```
db.employee.aggregate([
    {$facet: 
        {"total": [
            {$count: "total"}
        ]}
    }, 
    {$project:
        {"total": 1}
    }
])
```